# Accessing Opensearch Serverless from a Lambda in AWS

Tags: aws-lambda, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I'm trying to access my Opensearch Serverless collection using a Nodejs lambda. This is what my lambda code looks like:

```js
import { Client } from '@opensearch-project/opensearch';
const REGION = 'eu-central-1';
const SEARCH_ENDPOINT = 'some-endpoint.eu-central-1.es.amazonaws.com';

const client = new Client({
  node: SEARCH_ENDPOINT
});

export const handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    client.indices.create({ index: 'restaurants' }).then(() => {
      console.log(`Index restaurants created`);
    });

    
    await client.bulk({ body: somebody });

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: 'Data inserted into OpenSearch successfully.'
    };
  } catch (error) {
    //error handling
  }
};
```

However when trying to execute the lambda with some dummy event I get the following Access Denied error:

```
User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxx is not authorized to perform: aoss:APIAccessAll because no identity-based policy allows the aoss:APIAccessAll action
```

How can I make my Lambda access my AOSS collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation unluckily is not one of the best, but first off you need to create a data access policy inside your Opensearch Serverless collection where you add a rule with:

- as Principal: your lambda role
- as grants/permissions: based on what the lambda should do with the collection

[image]

[image]

If you don't know your lambda role, you can just go to your lambda detail page and then navigate to 'Configuration > Permissions' and its sitting right on top of that page

[image]

After that you should give to the lambda role the access policy to perform the aoss:APIAccessAll action. Now I didn't find any 'pre-made' access policy so I created a new one with name **OpensearchServerlessAPICaller** with the following json policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "aoss:BatchGetCollection",
                "aoss:APIAccessAll"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

With everything in place now your lambda CAN perform calls directly to your Opensearch Serverless collection. Meanwhile to actually perform calls you need to correctly authenticate, and using @opensearch-project/opensearch, means having something like this:

```
import { AwsSigv4Signer } from '@opensearch-project/opensearch/aws';
import { Client } from '@opensearch-project/opensearch';
import { defaultProvider } from '@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node'

const client = new Client({
  node: "Your opensearch host",
  ...AwsSigv4Signer({
    region: 'eu-central-1',
    service: 'aoss',

    getCredentials: () => {
      const credentialsProvider = defaultProvider();
      return credentialsProvider();
    },
  }),
});
```

The default credentials provider here should be fine since you are using a lambda after all

Sidenote: Keep in mind that if you opted to protect your opensearch collection within a VPC then you should place the lambda within the same VPC otherwise it's not going to reach the collection.